# Remove line at the top of first item in a Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am having this issue with a `Listview`, I have a `PagerSlidingTabs` with 4 tabs and a `ViewPager`, in the fist tab I have a fragment with a `Listview`.
The problem is that in the fist item of the list is a litle line that is not supposed to be there. I put the background of the `Lisview` Red so you can see this litle space that when I scroll is gone.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adList"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/matchDetailsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code of the tabs:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:pstsDividerColor="@color/transparent"
                    app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/bg_match_detail"
                    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="10dp"
                    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
                    app:pstsTabBackground="@color/transparent"
                    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="18dp"
                    app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"
                    app:pstsTriangleIndicator="true"
                    app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp" />
```

And here is what looks like when scroll the list (You can see that the space is gone) but when you are in the top of the list appears again:

[image]

Comment: android:background="@null"

Answer (score 0):

Use this-:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adList"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/matchDetailsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of-:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adList"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/matchDetailsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that I want to remove that space because when I put the background of the Listview transparent (that is how I want) the ligth blue of the first item is not exactly below the blue triangle. Because that little space